# unable to read session on SagePay server notification page

Tags: session, notifications, opayo

We integrate with SagePay Server using ASP.Net and we seem to have a problem getting session on our NotificationUrl.

We get no information when we try to read session on the Notification page, but strangely the page we set as RedirectUrl can read all the values from session. Can you please advise if we are doing anything wrong or if we have to pass any parameter to access session information on the notification page?

Thanks,

PS: I have also posted the question on SagePay support forum

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the request to `NotificationUrl` will be done from SagePay server and not customer PC, therefore request will not have customer's cookie/session id that is valid on your server. From your server point of view they (customer and request to NotificationUrl page) would be 2 different persons. Check your web server logs -- they will have different IPs and most (if not all) requests to NotificationUrl would be from the same IP (or IPs in the same subnet).

Answer (score 0):

The RedirectURL is usually a page hosted on your own site which is designed to be an order complete page that we redirect the shopper's web browser to upon transaction completion.

For more information on this, please check [Sage Pay Server Protocol and Integration Guidelines](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sage%20Pay%20Server%20Protocol%20and%20Integration%20Guidelines).